# How do I change the code to run synchronously

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have `comparePassword` function runs inside `checkLogin` in synchronous way, but the debugging output shows the opposite, what is my mistake here?

```
comparePassword = (password, salt, passwordHash) => {
  crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 64, "sha512", (err, derivedKey) => {
    //console.log('dump comparePassword: ', err);
    if (err) {
      return {
        status: 500,
        error: "Internal server error",
        detail: "Server couldn't check your credential at the moment"
      };
    } else {
      console.log(
        "dump dump ===   : ",
        passwordHash === derivedKey.toString("hex") ? true : false
      );
      if (derivedKey.toString("hex") == passwordHash) {
        console.log("return return return1: ", true);
        return true;
      }

      console.log("return return return2: ", true);
      return false;
    }
  });
};

// Check credentials of a seller
exports.checkLogin = async (username, password) => {
  let result = 0;
  try {
    const record = await Seller.findOne({
      raw: true,
      attributes: { exclude: ["birth", "createdAt", "updatedAt"] },
      where: { email: username }
    });

    if (record !== null) {
      let passwordRes = await comparePassword(
        password,
        record.salt,
        record.password
      );
      console.log("dump passwordRes: ", passwordRes);
      if (typeof passwordRes === "object") {
        return passwordRes;
      }

      if (passwordRes) {
        delete record.password;
        delete record.salt;
        return { seller: record };
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error while checking seller credential: ", error);
    result = {
      status: 500,
      error: "Internal server error",
      detail: "Server couldn't check your credential at the moment"
    };
  }

  return result;
};
```

Output:

```
dump passwordRes:  undefined
dump dump ===   :  true
return return return1:  true
```

Expectation:

```
dump dump ===   :  true
return return return1:  true
dump passwordRes:  true
```

Comment: Try giving `async` to `comparePassword` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comparePassword` should return an promise so `await` can wait till the promise is resolved or rejected

```
comparePassword = (password, salt, passwordHash) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 64, "sha512", (err, derivedKey) => {
      if (err) {
        reject({
          status: 500,
          error: "Internal server error",
          detail: "Server couldn't check your credential at the moment"
        });
      } else {
        if (derivedKey.toString("hex") == passwordHash) {
          resolve(true);
        }
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not await a callback in `comparePasswort` without wrapping it in a promise.

Try something like

```
comparePassword = (password, salt, passwordHash) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512', (err, derivedKey) => {
        // ...
        resolve(true); // or reject(false)
    })
})
```

Comment: You have the best explanation to my issue, **a callback must be wrapped in promise**.

Answer (score 0):

Return a promise or simply make it async:

```
comparePassword = async (password, salt, passwordHash) =>{}
```